# Assistance with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, search

I have a file that has records formatted like the one below.  The #ADDBANK is the header for each record and each record may have 0 or more rows that begin with //error!

I need a regular expression that will identify all records (beginning with #ADDBANK) that contain 1 or more rows that begin with //error! and return the following rows from that record:

- The row containing #ADDBANK
- The row in the corresponding record that begins with customerNumber
- Each row in the record that begins with //error!

For example, for the result of the regular expression for a file with the two sample records below would be the following.  Any regular expression experts out there that might be able to lend me a hand?

**Result**

```
#ADDBANK
customerNumber=10427856
//error!-error=SP02195:account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing. error=SP02195:account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing.
//error!-error=ufaEvent.process exception : account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing. error=ufaEvent.process exception : account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing.
```

**Sample File**

```
#ADDBANK
customerNumber=10427856
bankruptcy.filingDate=2015-12-10
bankruptcy.bankruptcyStatus=CONFIRM
bankruptcy.bankruptcyStatusDate=2015-12-10
bankruptcy.proofOfClaimType=FILINHOU
bankruptcy.proofOfClaimFilingDate=2015-12-31
bankruptcy.confirmationDate=2016-02-18
bankruptcy.caseNumber=19-10832
bankruptcy.chapterFiled=CHAPTER13
bankruptcy.creditUnionAgency=Virginia Eastern
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString9=0
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString6=ST LOUIS
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString4=JOHN DOE JR
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString13=0
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString8=63143
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafDate5=2016-09-07
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString7=MO
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString11=0
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString5=PO BOX 430908
//error!-error=SP02195:account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing. error=SP02195:account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing.
//error!-error=ufaEvent.process exception : account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing. error=ufaEvent.process exception : account.paymentSummary.statementFormat is not required when account.paymentSummary.statementIndicator is Suppress Statement-Create Billing.

#ADDBANK
customerNumber=10428256
bankruptcy.filingDate=2010-09-06
bankruptcy.bankruptcyStatusDate=2017-10-03
bankruptcy.bankruptcyStatus=FILED
bankruptcy.confirmationDate=2012-01-12
bankruptcy.chapterFiled=CHAPTER13
bankruptcy.creditUnionAgency=Western
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString6=Kansas City
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString4=Bob Martin
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString9=0
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString3=NO
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString8=64106
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString7=MO
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafDate5=2011-01-05
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString5=818 Test Blvd
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString11=0
bankruptcy.bankruptcyUAFAttributes.uafString13=0
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: We are using BareTail Pro

Comment: [Looks like it uses PCRE.](https://baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/regex.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to match these lines all you have to do is to match the end of each line. Using this regex

```
#ADDBANK|customerNumber.*|\/\/error.*
```

you will match all the required lines in your record. But using this regex you will have to loop over all the matches in order to collect all the matched lines.